# How can I remove arrows stuck in a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I am shot by an arrow in Minecraft, my avatar now has an arrow sticking out of me which hangs around for a while before disappearing. This is fine right now, but when I am trialing one of my redstone arrow traps, my MC avatar can look a little like this:

[image: My body with arrows in it]

Now I don't care about this when in singleplayer, because they don't block my vision when in 1st person. But I'm going to go into multiplayer soon, and having a bunch of arrows in my body will make me look hideous, and I'll be the laughingstock of all my friends if they see my with all these arrows.

I'd like any solution, whether it involves commands or glitches, or some hidden hack that I didn't know of, to get rid of these horrid arrows stuck in my body on my command, or better, to stop them from getting stuck on me in the first place!

## Past trials

Could killing the arrow entities work?

```
/kill @e[type=arrow]
```

Could clearing my inventory work?

```
/clear @s arrow
/clear @s
```

Comment: In my experience, arrows are a badge of honor because it shows you avoided dying even though you were hit so much.

Comment: @Firestryke These are not my actual views, this is a fictional situation. :)

Answer (score 3):

In 1.14+, if a player gets shot with an arrow that has `PierceLevel:1b` tag, the arrow won't be in the player model. Maybe that could help.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way around this is by having gamerules `doKeepInventory` and `doImmediateRespawn` set to true, and then a command block set your spawn where you are standing ex:

```
/execute at @p run spawnpoint @p ~ ~ ~
```

then another with

```
/kill @p
```

This should kill you, thus removing the arrows, but have no actual downsides.
Not sure if the writing for these commands are 100% accurate. I don't have them memorized

-replace `@p` with your minecraft username or any selector

Comment: I changed the command a bit because I think it's what you meant, but if you think/want otherwise feel free to undo it - the edited command should be a bit cleaner now

Answer (score 1):

it disappears after a while. you can die on purpose somehow and respawn, and the arrows will disappear when you will have respawned.

Comment: Of course they won’t laugh at me, that was just fictional. I was more looking for just a way to get rid of arrows more quickly than “a while.”

Answer (score 0):

Now this might sound stupid and strange but if you have a lava block with a respawn point right next to it you can die and respawn and the arrows will disappear

Answer (score -1):

You can't do anything about it actually  and most players don't care you have arrows because it just shows a player fought you or you got attacked by a skeleton they will disappear after a bit and that's all you can do wait for it

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there’s no way around it?

Comment: yes there is no way around it if you play on PC you could download mods but if your on a server that you don't own then you can't do anything

Comment: Well I'm still going to wait for the next answer. I refuse to believe that there is no way around this issue.

Comment: You can google it I migght be wrong coder but i believe taht you probably arent gonna get it